# Join images using Alibaba's OSS image processing

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am using Alibaba's Object Storage Service's image processing to process my images. I need a way to join (stitch) a few images together and create a larger image.

**Background:** I want to scale up an image to 7680 × 4320 (8k) resolution using the OSS image processing. But every time I do that, it fails as it only allows scaling images to a maximum dimension of 4096 x 4096.

A solution that I came up with, for this problem, was this:

1. ***Crop my image into 4 quarters resulting into 4 smaller images***

   Can be made possible with the help of the `Crop` operation to make parts of the initial image and the `Saveas` operation to save those images.
2. ***Independently scale up those 4 images to 1920 x 1080***

   Can be made possible using the `Resize` operation to scale up those image parts.
3. **Join those scaled images together to obtain the larger image**

   The documentation does not state any direct way to join images. I'm looking for a way or a workaround for the same.

How do I accomplish this 3rd step, so as to join those 4 images together to form the final 7680 × 4320 image output?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official [documentation for processing images with Alibaba Cloud's OSS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/44688.htm) it is evident it doesn't have any information on stitching images together.

If they have imposed a limit on the dimension it would be wise to assume that it is the highest you can go.

The documentation states:

> File size cannot exceed 20 MB

That's for the original image, and any image going as high as 8k resolution will mostly be larger than 20MB, so assuming it doesn't take an input that big we can conclude it won't produce that big output either.

To me it looks like you can only manipulate one image at a time and in that case you may not be able to stitch images with Alibaba Cloud OSS.

Maybe contacting support and letting them know this may prove to be helpful, as it is a limit that they have set, and then it lacks image stitching as well, so letting them know this may help improve it in future.

Answer (score 0):

Which region do you need to process images? Alibaba Cloud Function Compute can definitely help to achieve what you described, but as of 5/31/2018, the service is not available in all regions.

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/53097.htm